# Jquery autocomplete plugin version 1.2.2 not working

Tags: mysql, jquery, autocomplete

I am using Jörn Zaefferer’s auto-complete plugin 1.2.2. I can't use the newer version of the plugin which is included in Jquery UI. I am linking to a script on my server that sends both a job name, or a job id back in the search:

```
return_arr = array();

/* If connection to database, run sql statement. */
if ($connect)
{   
    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE job_name LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']) ."%' OR insert_id LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']) ."%' ORDER BY job_name ASC");

    /* Retrieve and store in array the results of the query.*/
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $key = $row['job_name']."-".$row['insert_id'];

        array_push($return_arr,$key);
    }
}

/*Sort Array*/
foreach ($return_arr as $value) {
    echo "$value\n";

}
```

I am using the following settings in javascript:

```
$("#job_select").autocomplete('../lib/job_select2.php', {  
        minChars: 0, 
        autoFill: true,  
        mustMatch: true,  
        matchContains: false, 
        scrollHeight: 220  
});
```

When I type a job name into the field, a list of jobs are presented that are built by the search string. And when I tab out of the field, the input stays.

When I type in a jobid though, it presents me with a list of jobs, but when I tab out of the field the entry disappears.  I know thats because mustMatch is true, but I need that to be set to true.  I don't want to accept any input that isn't already in the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you read the docs, comments in 2010 say plugin is deprecated. Chances are you are running into issues with more current version of jQuery than plugin supported when deprecated. Try jQueryUI autocmplete as subsititute and as sugegsted in docs.

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Comment: Updated my OP to say that I have to use 1.2.2. I can't use the newer version of the plugin that is included with Jquery UI.

Comment: not sure how to help other than suggest using a blur handler on the field